# Apply Max to each element of a list

Tags: map

I have a list

```
a = {1, 8, 0, 6, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5}
```

I want to generate a new list whose elements are the same of a if it's bigger than 5, or 5 elsewhere.
I managed to achieve this using Map and a pure function doing

```
Map[(Max[#, 5]) &, a]
```

but this looks a bit clumsy to me. Is there a better way?

EDIT: I found this solution

```
a /. x_ /; x < 5 -> 5
```

but I cannot really understand why is working. Could someone give an insight into it?

Thanks

Comment: Why not `Max[#, 5] & /@ a` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) or [`Ramp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html):

```
Clip[a, {5, ∞}]
```

> {5, 8, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}

```
5 + Ramp[a - 5]
```

> {5, 8, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}